# Connect lines that are separated by ^M character in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a CSV file. Because of some reasons, when I open it with `vim` in ubuntu, some lines appear to be like that :

```
This is actually ^M
a line.
```

I want the result to be :

```
This is actually a line.
```

So, I want to delete all `^M` characters and connect those lines separated by them.

Answer (score 2):

These may be multi-line cells saved from Excel. It looks as if you have carriage-return/linefeed pairs, as you have ^M (carriage return) followed by a line break.

The example you show has a space before the ^M - is that always the case?

To remove all carriage-return/linefeed pairs you could use:

```
:%s/\r\n//g
```

(\r is the escape sequence for carriage return, and \n is the escape sequence for linefeed or newline)

Or to replace them by spaces:

```
:%s/\r\n/ /g
```

Answer (score 1):

The ^M is a carriage return, probably this file was created in Windows. You could simply call `dos2unix filename.csv`

In vim you can do `:%s/^M//g`, (press <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>M</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to get the `^M`).

Answer (score 0):

First You should reopen the file with the correct lineendings:

```
:edit ++ff=dos
```

To prevent this mistake in the future, put this in to Your *.vimrc*:

```
set fileformats=unix,dos
```

Joining of lines should work now.

If you want to join only the lines with `^M` ending, then forgot the aboves and use this command:

```
:g/^M/ s/^M// | normal J
```

To type in `^M`, press `C-V` then `Enter`.

Comment: does :g/^M/ s/^M// | normal J apply to all the file ? I use it and it just apply some line. And then i have to type it again .

Comment: I can help more if You could give an example from the (original) file where the command does not works. You can upload it for example to https://gist.github.com/